# Why is a Ruby STDIN Enumerator not behaving as expected

Tags: ruby

An Enumerator in Ruby has a `peek` method that returns the next element but doesn't move the internal position forward.
An example demonstrating this behaviour using `Array.each` is

```
$ ruby -e "e=['a','b','c'].each;puts e.peek;puts e.next"
a
a
$ ruby -e "e=['a','b','c'].each;puts e.peek;e.each{|l| puts l}"
a
a
b
c
```

However, using `STDIN.each_line` as enumerator results in unexpected behaviour:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc" | ruby -e "e=STDIN.each_line;puts e.peek;puts e.next"
a
a
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc" | ruby -e "e=STDIN.each_line;puts e.peek;e.each{|l| puts l}"
a
b
c
```

Combining `peek` and `next` works fine in this case, but `peek` and `each` doesn't. What's the reason for this?

Comment: seems like this issue: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10534

Comment: @JensTimmerman I agree with you.. +1 .. report it as a _bug_.